# using a batch file, how can i delete all files not in the windows dir?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, prompt

i have a litle project for which i would like to remove all files outside of and not needed by the c:\windows operating system. therefore i need to create a list of what i want to keep i.e. boot.ini c:\windows etc and then delete everything else. i have seen examples using forFile, but i can be sure that extension will be on the machine. does anyone have any ideas how i can create the exclude list and then do the delete?

Comment: You'll potentially wreak havok with your registry.  How about restoring the drive from a ghost or similar backup?

Comment: I think you're doing it backwards. Unless you want to kill all the apps, just delete the user accounts.

Comment: @bliss: You can't delete the registry anyway from a running Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick stab at a list of top level folders you should not touch:

```
$Recycle.Bin
Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
inetpub
MSOCache
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
ProgramData
Recovery
System Volume Information
Users
Windows
```

On XP `Documents and Settings` is a folder, on Vista and 7 it's a link to the `Users` folder.

`MSOCache` is safe to delete as well. However, a lot of installer packages are cached there and used for various MS products updates/repairs. As such, I'd actually recommend keeping it.

`Program Files (x86)` is the redirected `Program Files` for 32-bit apps on 64-bit OS installs. However, I've seen applications that install in this folder instead of `Program Files` even on 32-bit OSes, so I'd advise on keeping it and manually inspecting its content to make a decision if it should be gone.

**Update:** There's no reliable way to list the OS files only. The list can vary widely between OS version, SKU, architecture, OS features installed, hardware drivers, OS updates and installed applications.

Comment: sure thing - however what files are required to only run the operating system, if i want to remove all user data?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to backup whichever method you implement.

:: you can define parameters so it know not include the folders you don't want and check it like so

```
IF "%2" == "" 
IF "%1" == "RunMyBatchFile" ^


FOR %%i IN (""%filter%) ^  ::directory name goes in here that you want to iterate over todelete
DO (^::Do your stuff, make sure to use echo to see the output on the cmd
) ^
```

Comment: thanks for your advice
looking at the list below ive going with 
For /F %I in ('dir /s /b "USERPROFILE%") do Del %I
which should, if the user puts their content in their user profile, remove it and not stop on errors.

thank again

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments about other folders than c:\Windows, a lot of common windows components go in Program Files\Common Files, and the application folders under Program Files are likely to have drivers that Windows won't boot normally without; AntiVirus, graphics and other non-default hardware drivers.

Here be dragons.

Comment: dragons indeed! basically i want to remove the user content, while leaving the operating sytem alone, avoiding OS warnings
thnx

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get rid of user data files, you only need to look in a couple of places, such as `%USERPROFILE%\AppData`. The actual directory names vary with the OS (XP/Vista/7).

But don't do it to the Administrator, or yourself!